# Android Lollipop transitions not working on App Bar Layout

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions, android-appbarlayout

I have two activities whose layout contains an app bar layout. A toolbar is nested inside the app bar layout. I'm applying activity transitions to go between A and B.

I defined a custom transition set where the app bar and toolbar slide top and the rest of the screen south of toolbar slides bottom. But, I'm not getting the desired effect. The toolbar slides up and the rest of the contents slide down, but the app bar stays there and it doesn't transition (slide up in my case) between activities.

Also I have tried adding `id/app_bar_layout` as `targetID` in the transition XML, and still doesn't slide up.

Comment: Show your XML. And which tutorial are you following?